# Celery worker doesn't see tasks from a specific Django app

Tags: python, django, celery

Can't understand why `celery worker` suddenly stopped discovering tasks from a specific app, i.e. it can find all tasks except the ones from the app (though it worked fine some time ago, no changes were made to the settings). Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?

Comment: app is there in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?. Please post INSTALLED_APPS and celery.py

Comment: Actually the problem was in `app.autodiscover_tasks()`, which suppresses any errors, and the reason was the following import line added to the corresponding tasks.py: `from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth`. That ImportError made workers **silently** discard all tasks from that file and for that particular app.